# Calling output from a factory from a view

Tags: angularjs

I need to access the var `utc` from a view. Here's my factory that should return `utc`.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('weatherapp.weatherlist')
.controller('WeatherlistController', function(utcFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.UTC = utcFactory.myUTC();
 })

.factory('utcFactory', function() {
    var myUTC = function() {
      var offset = -new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
      var utc = ((offset > 0 ? '+' : '') + offset / 60);
      return utc;
    }

    return {
      myUTC: myUTC
    }
});
})();
```

I've added `utcFactory` to the controller as in the below.

```
angular.module('weatherapp.weatherlist', ['weatherapp.locations'])
        .controller('WeatherlistController', ['$scope', 'LocationService', 'WEATHER_API_URL', 'WEATHER_API_IMAGE_URL', 'WEATHER_API_ID', 'WeatherListFactory', 'utcFactory',WeatherListCtrl]);
```

But for some reason I cannot access the `utc` var anywhere, when I try to test for it with console log I don't see it.

I'm trying to access it using 
 
 
{{utc}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my html

```
<ion-view view-title="Whatever The Weather">
    <ion-content>
        <div ng-show="noLocation" class="card">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <div class="item">
                    <p>There are currently no locations available. Feel free to add new ones.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-hide="noLocation" ng-repeat="weatherdata in locationData" class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider icon-left weatherlist-title">
                <img ng-src="{{weatherdata.weather[0].icon}}"><span>{{weatherdata.name}}, {{weatherdata.sys.country}} - {{weatherdata.weather[0].description}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><h2>Temperature:</h2></div>
                        <div class="col col-40"><b>{{weatherdata.main.temp | fahrenheit}} &deg;F / {{weatherdata.main.temp | roundme}} &deg;C</b></div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><h2>Sunset:</h2></div>
                        <div class="col col-30">{{weatherdata.sys.sunset | amFromUnix |  amLocal | amDateFormat:'HH:mm a'}} <span class="tiny" ng-bind="'utc ' + weatherdata.utc"></span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><h2>Wind Speed:</h2></div>
                        <div class="col col-30">{{weatherdata.wind.speed}} ms / {{weatherdata.wind.speed | mph}} mph</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><h2>Humidity:</h2></div>
                        <div class="col col-30">{{weatherdata.main.humidity}} %</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the factory method and attribute the value to a `$scope` variable.

Here's is a demonstration working:

```js
(function() {
   "use strict";
    angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('mainCtrl', function(utcFactory) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.utc = utcFactory.myUTC();
     })

    .factory('utcFactory', function() {
        var myUTC = function() {
          var offset = -new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
          var utc = ((offset > 0 ? '+' : '') + offset / 60);
          return utc;
        }

        return {
          myUTC: myUTC
        }
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <span class="tiny" ng-bind="'UTC => ' + main.utc"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I've almost got it I think. The ng-app tag is `<body ng-app="weatherapp">` The ng-repate tag is `ng-repeat="weatherdata in locationData"`, the controller I'm adding it to is `angular.module('weatherapp.weatherlist')
    .controller('WeatherlistController', function(utcFactory)`  I'm getting confused here somewhere with the scope, and these names need to stay the same to display the other info currently being displayed. Can you see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: No, just no utc in the view.

Comment: I've edited the above question, updated where I'm at :D

Comment: Pff, It was my mistake... please, change `vm.UTC` to `vm.utc`.

Comment: Ok, I have it working again. I had two controllers with the same name `WeatherlistController` - when I rename that to `WeatherlistController2` I get no errors again (it works), but I still don't see my utc var.

Comment: Did you changed `vm.UTC` to `vm.utc` in controller as I said?

Answer (score 1):

You can not get access utc var directly. You have defined a function called 'myUTC' which returns the value of **utc**.

In your controller, you must call `utcFactory.myUTC()` and this will returns the value of '**utc**'.

EDIT:

Create a variable in your scope controller, i.e., $scope.utc = utcFactory.myUTC() and this will be linked in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller -

```
$scope.utc =  utcFactory;
```

In your view -

```
<span class="tiny">{{utc.myUTC()}}</span>.
```